# Ubuntu 10.04 / Rails 2.3.11 / Applications are slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, ruby-on-rails-2

I see this in my rail's log:

```
Completed in 36594ms (View: 1, DB: 0) | 200 OK
```

From the looks of it, the View and DB were really fast at completing, but the entire request took 36594ms.

I'm suspecting it may be a server configuration and not Rails. Is there some immediate ideas that you may know just by seeing those numbers?

Sorry I know I'm not giving you much info to work with but I really don't know where to start but with that info.

Comment: Have you done any preliminary troubleshooting? Have you made any code changes recently which may have caused this? Have you restarted the machine? Have you tested using another server like *thin* or *puma*? Does the fault follow the code repo to another system? What happens if you try to do this under a different user account on the same machine? Do all Rails 2.3.11 apps behave so slowly? Which Ruby version? Are you using RVM? Is your app making any external api requests? Can you post your code on github?

Comment: is there anything else running on the server? Is it heavily loaded? What does your load and IO averages look like.